# What are the wires next to in ground electric box? Are they supposed to be exposed?

Tags: electrical

This photo is 30-50 yards from my house, by the street. I suspect it's the underground electrical wires going to my house?  You cannot tell from the photo but the upper side of the photo is a slope. It's possible that in the past 30 years, the ground shifted and exposed some wires.  Are they hot? Does color mean anything? I am planning to call the utility company. I am afraid kids may play with it or dogs may try to chew. Just wanted to see if anyone here has a comment.[image]

Comment: They look like low voltage wiring to me. Do you have landscape lighting?

Comment: To be safe call.  They might be electric or telephone/ISP/cable.  Electric wires usually come in threes, but one might still be buried, so no help there.

Comment: No I do not have landscape lighting.

Comment: They could also be irrigation related. Have you opened the box?

Comment: Irrigation system I have. There is no way I am touching that box without knowing what is in it! These wires are too thick to be irrigation wires to me.

Comment: Do you have street lights that are fed from underground wires?  If so, it could be a street light circuit. That's about the size of the handholes they use.

Comment: I have low voltage driveway lights, but the lights and this box is at the different side of the house.

Comment: Barring some major violations or more than 24" of soil erosion (seems unlikely as the box would have been buried), they won't be line voltage wires. Sometimes communications stuff will end up in a box marked "electric" because those were in stock and one marked otherwise was not. Or the box has line voltage stuff in it, but the exposed wires don't go into the box... Looks like CATV coax with a molded-in suspension wire parallel to the coax itself. And half-donkey-ing the install  is a typical CATV move, based on past examples I've seen. You could try a NCVT on it, if you have one.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Your suggestion was a good one. I have good NCVT and tested it. It indicates no voltage. It might be CATV coax or Fios fiber optic wire as you said. I may open the box sometime to see what is in it.

Answer (score 5):

Hard to tell for sure, but those wires don't look nearly thick enough to be your home electric service. So my suspicion is cable TV or telephone or, as noted in a comment, possible something that is part of the property itself such as landscape lighting or sprinkler system controls.

But since there is an "ELECTRIC" box right next to the wires, starting with your local electric utility makes sense.